# Predictable Projection in is a Hilbert Space Projection?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, hilbert-spaces, stochastic-analysis

Recently I began reading about predictable projections of stochastic processes.  Suppose that $X_t$ is a $(F_t)$-adapated stochastic process defines on a stochastic base $(\Omega,(F_t)_{0\leq t\leq T},\mathbb{P})$ and let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.  Suppose that $X_t$ satisfies the $L^2$-integrability condition:
$$
E\left[
\int_0^T |X_t|^2 dt
\right]<\infty
$$
i.e.: $X_T$ is $L^2_{P\otimes m}(F_T\otimes \Omega) $ then can the [predictable projection](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/tag/predictable-projection/) of $X_t$ onto the predictable filtration be understood as a [Hilbert space projection](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-017-0223-2_11) of $X_T$ onto $L^2_{P\otimes m}(Pred)$; where $Pred$ is the predictable $\sigma$-algebra?